# How to write a batch file that runs an exe on a number of files in a specified folder in windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have 50 jpg files at location `"C:\steghide\train\"`. The steghide.exe is located inside steghide folder `"C:\steghide\"`. I want to run this exe recursively on all images to embed message.txt. I am using the following code:

```
@echo off
title Embed Secret
cd C:\steghide\
for %%f in (C:\steghide\train\*.jpg) do steghide embed -cf "C:\steghide\train\*.jpg" -ef "message.txt"
```

Getting error could not open the file `C:\steghide\train\*.jpg`

Comment: Ever bothered to read the help of `for` when typing `for /?` into a command prompt window?

Comment: You are handing the literal "C:\steghide\train\*.jpg" to the steghide program.  It doesn't seem to understand the wildcard `*`.  Replace that with `%%F` and see what happens.

Comment: By "run this recursively" do you mean iterate over all the files in that directory or do you wish to also recurs into sub-directories?

Comment: Since you haven't done so already, I recommend that you take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  You did okay on the MCVE part, but you should have searched through some of the similar questions here.  Pretty sure we can find a dupe of essentially this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
FOR %%G IN ("C:\steghide\train\*.jpg") DO ("C:\steghide\steghide.exe" "%%G")
```

Comment: It would help if you could explain why that is better than the OP's version of the code.  Like the fact they failed to use %%F in the body of their for statement and that %%f and %%F can be confused with the `%%~f` modifier (though that's not the problem here).  Why use the /f form? What's the point of clearing delims?